# Select summary lines from table data in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server-2014

This query is run in SQL Server 2014. The list is ordered by `KEY1 (unique),  ondate, ontime`.

The query is as follows:

```
SELECT 
    CB.KEY1,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ONDATE, 111) AS 'ONDATE',
    [ONTIME],
    (SELECT COUNT(CHC.srectype)
     FROM [dbo].[COS_BLUES] CHC
     LEFT OUTER JOIN COS_BLUESPROFDATE CPD ON CHC.key1 = CPD.KEY1
     WHERE CHC.key1 = CB.key1 AND CHC.SRECTYPE = 'C' 
       AND CHC.ONDATE >= CHC.UBRHDATE) AS 'CALL_COUNT',
    [OWNER] AS 'REC_OWNER',
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [CALLBACKON], 111) AS 'CALLBACKON',
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),[LASTCONTON], 111) AS 'LASTCALLDATE',
    DATEDIFF(DAY, [LASTCONTON], GETDATE()) AS'CONTACTDAYS',
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [UROLLDATE], 111) AS 'UROLLDATE',
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [ULASTSALE], 111) AS 'ULASTSALE',
    DATEDIFF(DAY, [ULASTSALE], GETDATE()) AS 'SALEEXPIRYDAYS',
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [UBRHDATE], 111) AS 'UBRHDATE',
    DATEDIFF(DAY, UBRHDATE, GETDATE()) AS 'REALLOCATIONDAYS',
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CPD.LASTDATE, 111) AS 'LASTPROFILEUPDATE',
    [REGION] AS 'LASTREGION',
    [USERID] AS 'LASTUSER'
FROM 
    [dbo].[COS_BLUES] CB
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    COS_BLUESPROFDATE CPD ON CB.key1 = CPD.KEY1
ORDER BY 
    CB.Key1, CB.ONDATE, CB.ONTIME
```

[image]

I do not know how to extract only the yellow lines.

Any assistance is appreciated.

Cheers
Bernard

Answer (score 0):

Your question lacks information, so, by reading the picture provided and trying to find a pattern for the *yellow lines*, I'm assuming what you want is to **group all records by `KEY1`** and **get the last row for each group**.

This query reproduces the described above:

```sql
SELECT * FROM ( /* this line is new */
    SELECT CB.KEY1
    ,convert(varchar(10),ONDATE,111) as 'ONDATE'
    ,[ONTIME]
    ,(select count(CHC.srectype)
        FROM [dbo].[COS_BLUES] CHC
        Left  outer join COS_BLUESPROFDATE CPD on CHC.key1 = CPD.KEY1
        where CHC.key1 = CB.key1 and CHC.SRECTYPE = 'C' and CHC.ONDATE >= 
        CHC.UBRHDATE) as 'CALL_COUNT'
    ,[OWNER] as 'REC_OWNER'
    ,convert(varchar(10),[CALLBACKON],111) AS 'CALLBACKON'
    ,convert(varchar(10),[LASTCONTON],111) as 'LASTCALLDATE'
    ,DateDiff(day,[LASTCONTON],getdate())  as 'CONTACTDAYS'
    ,convert(varchar(10),[UROLLDATE],111) as 'UROLLDATE'
    ,convert(varchar(10),[ULASTSALE],111) as 'ULASTSALE'
    ,DateDiff(day,[ULASTSALE],getdate())  as 'SALEEXPIRYDAYS'
    ,convert(varchar(10),[UBRHDATE],111) as 'UBRHDATE'
    ,DateDiff(day,UBRHDATE,getdate())  as 'REALLOCATIONDAYS'
    ,convert(varchar(10),CPD.LASTDATE,111) as'LASTPROFILEUPDATE'    
    ,[REGION] as 'LASTREGION'
    ,[USERID] as 'LASTUSER'
    ,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by CB.KEY1 ORDER BY CB.KEY1 DESC) as MAX_ID /* this line is new */
    FROM [dbo].[COS_BLUES] CB
    Left  outer join COS_BLUESPROFDATE CPD on CB.key1 = CPD.KEY1
    order BY CB.Key1 , CB.ONDATE , CB.ONTIME
) /* this line is new */
GROUP BY [KEY1] /* this line is new */
ORDER BY [MAX_ID] DESC /* this line is new */
```

*This query was not tested because the table schemas were not shared*, but you get the idea.

Comment: Sorry about the limited information.

When I run this code @Welder I get the following error message:

Msg 1033, Level 15, State 1, Line 26
The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.

The line specified as an error is actually line 25.

I am trying to add the DDL for the 2 tables, but I get an error message that it is 108 chars too long. 

 How can I include this?

Comment: I am using SSMS 2014  connected to a SQL Server 2008 R2 db

Comment: Hey Bernard, please, provide the table schema and an insert batch so I can test it out

Comment: Hi @welder

How do I post the table definition as for CREATE tablename to this question? 

That is what you mean by table schema?

The same goes for the insert sql.

I cannot find any help in StackOverflow; bar what I saw when I first posted the question.

All assistance is appreciated.

Cheers
Bernard

Comment: How do I add the code & data elements to this question?